# Cleanup more tools tags

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, tags, retag-request, burninate-request

In relation to the recent request [to burn the tools tag](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/202684/burninate-tools) I have found a few more "tools" tags which attract questions asking for tool recommendations.

I suggest we cleanup all of the following tags and then either burninate them or make them synonyms of their non *-tools variation (eg. make [code-anaylsis-tool](/questions/tagged/code-anaylsis-tool) a synonym of [code-anaylsis](/questions/tagged/code-anaylsis))

[design-tool](/questions/tagged/design-tool) (2)
[design-tools](/questions/tagged/design-tools) (8)
[development-tools](/questions/tagged/development-tools) (31)
[collaboration-tools](/questions/tagged/collaboration-tools) (36)
[code-analysis-tool](/questions/tagged/code-analysis-tool)  (40)
[build-tools](/questions/tagged/build-tools) (51)
[web-analytics-tools](/questions/tagged/web-analytics-tools) (62)
[developer-tools](/questions/tagged/developer-tools) (192)
[software-tools](/questions/tagged/software-tools) (527)

[Open Questions with any of the above tags](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=closed:no%20%5Bsoftware-tools%5D%20or%20%5Bdesign-tools%5D%20or%20%5Bdesign-tool%5D%20or%20%5Bbuild-tools%5D%20or%20%5Bcode-analysis-tool%5D%20or%20%5Bcollaboration-tools%5D%20or%20%5Bdevelopment-tools%5D%20or%20%5Bweb-analytics-tools%5D)

Comment: I'd agree with @Wooble 's comment on the refered question. Might be a working list for searching possible close candidates.

Answer (score 7):

This answer is to keep track of how many of these still need to be closed / looked at.

@any3k+user keep in mind that you can filter on these tags with the close review queue if you wish to get a few reviews in (if they already have close votes / flags).

- [design-tool](/questions/tagged/design-tool) - Gone
- [design-tools](/questions/tagged/design-tools) - Gone
- [development-tools](/questions/tagged/development-tools) - Gone
- [collaboration-tools](/questions/tagged/collaboration-tools) - Gone
- [code-analysis-tool](/questions/tagged/code-analysis-tool) - Gone
- [build-tools](/questions/tagged/build-tools) - [34 open](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bbuild-tools%5D+closed%3Ano)

  Keep / retag to / synonym of [build](/questions/tagged/build)?
- [developer-tools](/questions/tagged/developer-tools) - [164 open](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bdeveloper-tools%5D+closed%3Ano)

  Might be a useful tag, as some of these relate to developer tools of browsers (which are seemingly appropriate questions).

  We also have browser-specific versions of this - [ie11-developer-tools](/questions/tagged/ie11-developer-tools), [ie-developer-tools](/questions/tagged/ie-developer-tools), [firefox-developer-tools](/questions/tagged/firefox-developer-tools), [google-chrome-devtools](/questions/tagged/google-chrome-devtools). Having both seems redundant. I prefer the single one, but I guess some people may prefer the browser-specific one.

  There's also [devtools](/questions/tagged/devtools), which is supposed to be an R package (according to the tag wiki), but [most of the questions don't have the R tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/devtools+-r).
- [software-tools](/questions/tagged/software-tools) - [184 open](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bsoftware-tools%5D+closed%3Ano)

Comment: I think the [development-tools] tag should be removed in favor of the more specific browser tools tags: [ie-developer-tools] [google-chrome-devtools] or [firefox-developer-tools]

Comment: @Kara It might be useful to only have one tag, e.g. to find all questions about developer tools (separate tags tend to make it a bit more difficult). You can look for questions regarding some browser's tools with e.g. `[google-chrome] [developer-tools]` (which makes separate tags somewhat redundant). Although it might be wise to rename it to prevent misuse (to e.g. `[browser-dev-tools]`)

Comment: "developer tools of browsers (which are seemingly appropriate questions)." shouldn't use the browser tag instead?

Comment: @Braiam All questions with a browser tag isn't necessarily about the developer tools of that browser.

Comment: I meant, clean up and disambiguation preferring browser-dev-tools tags when applicable and removing where needed.

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest a delayed cleanup to give the community the ability to check the affected questions for possible close candidates.

Answer (score 0):

The reason that we should get rid of the tools tag is that every tool should have their own tag.  You tag something with the environment/applicaton/framework and you tag it with the specific tool that you have a question about.  For example, [puppet](/questions/tagged/puppet) and [hiera](/questions/tagged/hiera).

This will allow for much better searching by those wanting to find answers about that tool.